# Deploying Ubuntu on Hyper-v

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

Is there any way to deploy a new VM running ubuntu server on hyper-v without using a PXE server?

Do I have to use a iso image and do the whole "next next next", or is there at least a way to provide an answer file?

Thank you!

Comment: Not that I know of, but see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts. You might be able to find pre-installed images such as https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/yakkety/current/ (server only) or http://www.pwrusr.com/downloads (Ubuntu 14.04). What's the motivation for your question?

Comment: We use windows deployment services to deploy the windows servers we use and we can't deploy ubuntu server with it.
There are ways to use pxelinux to deploy ubuntu servers or boot to windows deployment services but that's not too stable and doesn't work great with UFI.

Also sometimes we don't have pxe services on a client's site and we need to deploy ubuntu servers.
I'd love to be able to have a minimal ubuntu iso and point it to a web hosted answer file, like for instance https://hostname/ubuntu.seed